# SSIS dynamically put rowcount in flat file destination expression name

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to create a filename dynamically.
I'm able to get the date but i need the rowcount of the data that was read from the odbc source.

I created a int32 variable called 'rowcount'.  And in the expression for the flat file connection manager 'connection string' property I have the following:

```
"E:\\path\\" + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + "_" + (DT_WSTR, 20) @[User::rowcount]  +".csv"
```

which gives :

> E:\folderpath\20151218_0.csv

But when I run the project it is creating the file name with 0 instead of the row count.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't describe what you are doing to actually populate the `rowcount` variable.   Did you forget that step?

Comment: sorry I did.  I put a row count after the odbc source.
odbc source --> row count --> flat file destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that your flat file is getting created (and therefore, named) before your DataFlow runs, when your rowcount variable is still zero because it hasn't been populated yet.

The only way to handle this is to rename the flat file after you have populated it and gotten the rowcount.   And the only way to do this is with a Script Task that runs after your DataFlow task.

Comment: thanks much.  I was able to use a file system task instead to rename the file in the control flow.